# VB.NET で IJCADのオブジェクトがどのグループに属しているのか知りたいです。

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

Groupオブジェクトの検索の方法を教えて下さい。
または、
Entityオブジェクトから所属しているGroupオブジェクトを取得することはできますでしょうか？

[2019.11.13]
いただきましたヒントを元に下記のコードを書きましたやりたいことは、
ポリラインを検索を検索して、そのポリラインが属しているグループを見つける
というものです。しかしながら実行すると
例外がスローされました: 'System.AccessViolationException' (gmdb.dll の中)
が発生して処理が止まってしまいます。

原因わかれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

```vb
        Using trans As Transaction = wdb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
            Dim acBlkTbl As BlockTable = trans.GetObject(wdb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
            Dim wcount = 0
            Dim wselobjs As PromptSelectionResult
            wselobjs = wed.SelectAll()
            If wselobjs.Status = PromptStatus.OK Then
                wcount = wselobjs.Value.Count
            End If
            For ix = 0 To wcount - 1
                Dim acObjId As ObjectId = wselobjs.Value(ix).objectid
                Dim wname As String = acObjId.ObjectClass().DxfName
                If wname = "LWPOLYLINE" Then
                    Debug.Print("POLYLINE")
                    Dim objPolyLine As Polyline = trans.GetObject(acObjId, OpenMode.ForRead, True)
                    Dim wgrps As ObjectIdCollection = objPolyLine.GetPersistentReactorIds()
                    For Each objId1 As ObjectId In wgrps
                        Dim wgrp As Group = trans.GetObject(objId1, OpenMode.ForRead, True)
                        If Not IsNothing(wgrp) Then
                            Dim wents As ObjectId() = wgrp.GetAllEntityIds()
                            Debug.Print(wents.ToString())
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

図面内のすべてのグループを取得する場合は、GDatabase.GroupDictionaryIdのObjectIdからDBDictionaryを取得し、この辞書内に存在するObjectIdから取得したオブジェクトがGroupオブジェクトです。

グループに属しているエンティティからグループを取得する場合は、GetPersistentReactorIdsメソッドを使用してエンティティからObjectIdのコレクションを取得し、このコレクション内のidにGroupオブジェクトのObjectIdが存在しますので、それを開くことでGroupオブジェクトを取得できます。

Comment: 手元にあるIJCADで試してみたところ、最新版のIJCADでは問題ありませんでしたが、IJCAD2018だと例外がスローされました。
旧バージョンの製品はAPIになにかしたの不具合があるのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私もうまく処理できず、また複数回実行すると例外が発生してしまい悩んで折りました。最新バージョンで改めて確認してみます。

Comment: 最新バージョンで作成したコードを質問に追記させていただきました。しかしながら例外がスローされてしまいます。最新版IJCAD2018です。検証いただいた最新版IJCADとは2019でしょうか？

Comment: GetPersistentReactorIdsメソッドが正常に動作していることを確認できたのは、IJCAD2019の最新版で、IJCAD2018では例外がスローされることを確認しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。IJCAD2019へのバージョンアップを検討します。

Comment: IJCAD2019にて実行すると正常に動作することが確認できました